# Android - TextView ignoring "wrap_content"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've got a problem with creating a layout in Android.

I have a linear layout which should display a TextView, EditView and Button from Top to bottom.
Problem is that when I set the width and height attribute of the TextView to "wrap_content" it behaves like "fill_parent" and fills the whole screen in width and height. 
As a conclusion the 2 other elements(EditView and Button) won't be shown.

I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my XML file:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_nickname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/label_nickname"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_nickname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_insert_nickname"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="-1"
        android:shadowDy="-1"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_play"
        style="@style/MainButtonTheme"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="click_playButton"
        android:text="@string/button_start" />
<  /  LinearLayout>
```

Looking forward to your input.

Lots of greetings

Siggy

Edit:

MainButtonStyle:

```
    <style name="MainButtonTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/states_menu_button</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Edit #2:

Here are the screenshots of how it looks like right now and what is desired:

Current state:

[image]

Desired state:

[image]

I tested it on the phone and it looks like this on the phone as well.

Comment: This isn't happening if I run the code. If none of the answers help you, can you try checking the view hierarchy and other tools to trace where those buttons and edit text are? Post their snapshots too.

Comment: Hey, I tried your layout as it is, its displaying fine in emulator, can you show me your output, what you are getting?

Comment: I added 2 screenshots. I tested it on the phone and it looks exactly like in the emulator. The 2 elements get pushed out of the visible screen by the textview :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys I found the problem.
It seems like a bug to me.

In my styles file I had defined a background for the whole application like this:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/app_background</item>
    </style>
```

When I removed the following line:

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/app_background</item>
```

The TextView with wrap_content behaves like it should.

I really don't know what the background image has to do with it.
Would be glad if someone could tell me :)

Greetings

Siggy

Answer (score 2):

As I found the solution to this, and there is no correct answers.

The problem was, because you used: name="android:background"
It sets not the background of whole app, but of every View. You should use: name="android:windowBackground" to set background only for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"

              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_nickname"
            android:layout_width="10dip"
            android:layout_height="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_nickname"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="-1"
            android:shadowDy="-1"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_play"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:onClick="click_playButton"
            android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it out, I made some changes i.e removed the style attribute:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_nickname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="label_nickname"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_nickname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="hint_insert_nickname"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDx="-1"
    android:shadowDy="-1"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<Button
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:onClick="click_playButton"
    android:text="button_start" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_nickname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/label_nickname"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_nickname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_insert_nickname"
                    android:shadowColor="#000000"
                    android:shadowDx="-1"
                    android:shadowDy="-1"
                    android:shadowRadius="1"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_play"
        style="@style/MainButtonTheme"
        android:onClick="click_playButton"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_start" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried this with Relative layout and it worked for me, See if it helps.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F88017" 
   >


    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/text_nickname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Nickname"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_nickname"
        android:id="@+id/edit_nickname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="insert_nickname"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="-1"
        android:shadowDy="-1"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_nickname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="click_playButton"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The textview only displays the string "Nickname". So that shouldn't be too much ;)

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of current and what is desired?

Comment: Added it to my question. If I use your code I can see the other 2 elements (edit and button) if I scroll down for about 2 screen lengths...